# Relation between $f^*$ and $f_*$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous map. Suppose the induced map in homology $f_*:H_*(X)\to H_*(Y)$ is given by $f_*(a) = b$. Consider the induced map in cohomology $f^*:H^*(Y)\to H^*(X)$ and suppose $\operatorname{Ext}$ term vanishes i.e., $H^*(X)\simeq \operatorname{Hom}(H_*(X),\Bbb Z)$ and $H^*(Y)\simeq\operatorname{Hom}(H_*(Y),\Bbb Z)$. Is it true that $f^*(\beta) = \alpha$ in this case? Here, $\alpha$ is a dual of $a$ and $\beta$ is a dual of $b$. Do I need to assume further both are generators? I basically want to see some relationship between $f^*$ and $f_*$ in general case and especially when the above case happens.

If someone want to know some concrete example I'm in concern, I'll edit the post.

Comment: $f_*$ "given by"? This is a definition?

Comment: @КряжевАрсений I want to see the relation between $f^*$ and $f_*$ by how they behave on each elements. I chose a cycle $a\in H_*(X)$ and let $b\in H_*(Y)$ by $b:=f_*(a)$. Well, $f_*$ is defined by $f$ and I essentially defined $b$ in the post.

Comment: "$f_*$ given by" means that $b=f_*(a)$ is the definition of $f_*$. But it is the definition of $b$.

Comment: Anyway, $f^*(\beta)(b') = \beta(f_*(b'))$ which is $1$ for any $b'$ in the preimage of $a$. E.g. just map two points to one point and let $b$ be generated by one point in the domain.